# Parsing text file in windows command file with findstr

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing bat-file to use several executable files (tools that I cannot change) sequentially.
Firs of the tool receive two file names and produce txt file.

Example 1:

```
Best score for a1_score.txt: 5712
Best score for a2_score.txt: 14696
```

Example 2:

```
Best score for data\a1_score.txt: 3023
Best score for data\a2_score.txt: 451
```

Example 3:

```
Best score for D:\tmp\a1_score.txt: 234
Best score for D:\tmp\a2_score.txt: 1062
```

Strings are different because of including full file path. But, fortunately names of file ("a1_score.txt " and "a2_score.txt") will not be changed.

I need two numbers to call next tool, so I tried to write script … but I'm not familiar with the command language and examples I have found in the Internet are not so useful.
Please, help ne to complete the following code:

```
if exist scores.dat goto scores
echo Cannot read scores
goto BADEND

:scores
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /c:a1_score.txt /c:a2_score.txt "scores.dat"') do (
    set str=%%a
    :: some code to create a1_score and a2_score with corresponding values

)
echo %a1_score%
echo %a2_score%

:: some other code

goto END
:BADEND
echo Process was not completed due to errors
:END
pause
```

Comment: Can we assume that the paths in the file will not have spaces?

Comment: @SomethingDark: Let's assume that spaces are not important and we can delete all the spaces in each line read from file

Comment: I was planning on using the spaces as a line delimiter...

Comment: @SomethingDark: I am not sure that paths in the file will not have spaces, but we can assume that for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code snippet could help:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set "scores_dat=%~dp0files\scores32003340.dat"   :: my filename value for debugging
if exist "%scores_dat%" goto scores

echo Cannot read scores
goto BADEND

:scores
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%a in ('
  findstr /R "a[12]_score.txt" "%scores_dat%"
  ') do (
    if "%%c"=="" (
      set str=%%a
      set /A "!str:~-12,8!=%%b"
    ) else (
      set str=%%b
      set /A "!str:~-12,8!=%%c"
    )
)
set a|find /I "score"
echo(%a1_score%
echo(%a2_score%

:: some other code

goto END
:BADEND
echo Process was not completed due to errors
:END
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`for` special page) [FOR loop summary: all variants](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: That works for Examples 1 and 2. I think it is enough for me now. Can you provide me link to manual which clearly explain `findstr` with `tokens`, `delims`, `%%a`, `%%b`, etc.?

Comment: @JozefZ: What is the best way to check if the `a1_score` and `a2_score` exists after `for` execution?

Comment: @VolAnd - [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files. - [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command. - [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: @VolAnd OOPS! I have passed over `:` colon in data example #3. Updated.

Comment: Thanks! Your help is really useful